# Having npm start Issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm, npm-start

I created a React app with npx create-react-app and installed with npm install, then cd'd to correct directory and hit npm start - fine everything working as intended in browser.

I then close the browser and run npm start and get this message:

```js
***** npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jacma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-29T11_03_32_182Z-debug-0.log
```

I struggled to find a solution and decided to just start again. Loaded new vs code and repeated initial steps and everything was working fine (specifically npm start). I then closed the tab localhost3000 I was in and tried to run npm start again and got the same error message.

Why am I having an issue with npm start, when I have "start": "react-scripts start" in my scripts in package.json and the command initially works after npx create, but not after it has already run, but works fine after I encountered the issue in a new project?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jake

Comment: can you share your package.json file here?

Comment: Are you in the same directory as your package.json in the terminal where you are running `npm run start`?

Comment: @geeky01adarsh my package.json file contains:

https://codepen.io/jake-matthews/pen/YzRVVPa

I'm pretty sure it's correct?

Comment: @omeanwell see screenshot of my file structure and cd that I am executing npm start in - IMGBB link https://ibb.co/VQdcTyC 

I'm confident that is correct, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to run the command from a different directory, it won't find your package.json file and the Missing script: "start" npm error is caused.

If you don't have a package.json file, create one by opening your terminal in your project's root directory and running the command npm init -y.

shell
npm init -y

Link: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/npm-missing-script-start

Comment: @Luce_Sanna - yes I realised that eventually, thank you.